# Pointers dereferencing, bad pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to program an encrptor and decryptor. My problem is a pointer that I assigned value first still has the same value as the second. I tried to use free but the problem is still the same.
For example, I typed aslkdjlasc(sample only)
and the output would be:
helloworld

I try to run the program again, then I type daskjda
the output would be like
doctorxRLD

RLD is from the past value of this pointer. It's supposed to be 7 characters only, but since helloworld is 10, the first 7 letters are replaced by the encryption but the last 3 characters are still printed.

What do I do?

UPDATE: HERE IS PART OF THE CODE:

```
void encrypt(char *crypt)
{
char *plaintext,*encryption,slash=0x2F;
int i,j,k,flags,f;
encryption=(char *)malloc(sizeof(int));
plaintext=(char *)malloc(sizeof(int));
printf("Enter plaintext, spaces,commas,and dots should be represented as /:\n");
scanf("%s",&*plaintext);
for(i=0;i<strlen(plaintext);i++)
{
    j=1;flags=0;
    while(j<53 && flags==0)
    {
        if(plaintext[i]==slash)
        {
            encryption[i]=slash;
            flags=1;
        }
        if(plaintext[i]==crypt[j])
        {
            encryption[i]=crypt[j-1];
            flags=1;
        }
        k=j+2;
        j=k;
    }
}
printf("%s",encryption);
    free(encryption);
    free(plaintext);
getch();
}
```

HERE IS THE MAIN

```
main()
{
char c;
int timer;
char crypt[53]="***i have hidden my encryption code***";
clrscr();
printf("Press e to encrypt, d to decrypt, ESC to exit.\n");
c=getch();
switch(c)
{
    case(0x1b):
        exit(0);
        break;
    case(0x64):
        decrypt(crypt);
        break;
    case(0x65):
        encrypt(crypt);
        break;
    default:
        printf("INVALID. FORCE EXIT IN 3 SEC0NDS.");
        delay(3000);
        exit(0);
}

getch();
}
```

Comment: `free()` doesn't set pointer to NULL, add your code here

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix code we don't see. You're doing something wrong, but exactly what is impossible to tell without the corresponding code.

Comment: It seems like you're missing a string terminator. Please post some relevant code or this will be hard to answer.

Comment: can you post your code??

Comment: Read your question again. Would you be able to pull out something useful if you read it?

Comment: I posted the code already. Thanks in advance guys. And glglgl you could've asked nicely, no need to be harsh.

Comment: Your mallocs are all wrong. Go back to your C book and re-read the part that deals with pointers and memory management. (And don't cast the return value of malloc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's me. I got it already. Thanks to all your comments though some are harsh. haha

1. I refrained from using malloc because apparently DCoder points out I do not know how to use them.
2. Thanks Sanyam Goel I have fixed my scanf too.
3. I used only 2 pointers instead of 4. What I did was I instantiated them in the main function instead of in each of the decrpyt and encrypt functions. Like this:

   `main()
   {
   char c,*from, *to; ..........`

   `void encrypt(char *crypt,char *plaintext,char *encryption)`

   `void encrypt(char *crypt,char *ciphertext,char *decryption)`

So when I call either of them, I just put:

```
    case(0x64):
        decrypt(crypt,from,to);
        break;
    case(0x65):
        encrypt(crypt,from,to);
        break;
```

And at the end of the switch in the main function:

```
    free(from); from=NULL;
    free(to); to=NULL;
```

So now I have eliminated unnecessary pointers and extra processes.

THANK YOU EVERYONE. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are allocating integer size (4 bytes ) of memory for a string

When you do

```
plaintext=(char *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Then by doing this

```
scanf("%s",&*plaintext);
```

your are possibly scanning a string of size more than that four characters ( however you allocated only four bytes) also

`scanf("%s",&*plaintext);` is equivalent to `scanf("%s",plaintext);` ( with the previous statement you are adding unnecessary computations.

Comment: Actually, by allocating the size of `int` there is only room for *three* characters in the string, as one has to be saved for the string terminator.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes exactly ;)